# Why are my subfloats not aligned?

Tags: tables, graphics, floats, subfloats, multicol

I am putting a figure and a table side by side:

```
\documentclass[format=acmsmall, review=false, screen=true]{acmart}

\usepackage{multicol}      % http://ctan.org/pkg/multicols
\usepackage{balance}       % to better equalize the last page
\usepackage{graphicx}      % for EPS, load graphicx instead    
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth, keepaspectratio]{OSM_copy.png}\label{OSM}}
    \subfloat[]
    {
    \resizebox{0.5\columnwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5.5ex}  \bf Location Type & \bf Index & \bf Location Type & \bf Index  \\ 
        \hline
        \hline \rule[-1ex]{0pt}{5.5ex}  Bar & \raisebox{-0.1cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{index_bar.png}} & Taxi stand &  \raisebox{-0.1cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{index_taxi.png}}\\ 
        \hline \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5.5ex}  Food court &  \raisebox{-0.3cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{index_foodcourt.png}} & Hospital &  \raisebox{-0.2cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{index_hospital.png}} \\ 
        \hline \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5.5ex}  Library &  \raisebox{-0.2cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{index_library.png}} & Pharmacy &  \raisebox{-0.2cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{index_pharmacy.png}} \\ 
        \hline \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5.5ex}  Fuel station &  \raisebox{-0.2cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{index_fuel.png}} & Movie theater &  \raisebox{-0.2cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{index_movie.png}} \\ 
        \hline \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5.5ex}  Parking &  \raisebox{-0.1cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{index_parking.png}} & Public telephone &  \raisebox{-0.2cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{index_phone.png}} \\
        \hline 
    \end{tabular}}
    \label{table2}
    }
    \caption[]{(a) An area in Taipei showing different location types. (b) Some of the location types defined in OSM. }
    \label{fig:location}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And this is the output I am getting:

[image]

Why are they not appearing in the same "plane"? And how do I rectify it?

Here is the link to download the image files used in the above code:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B54tuvGDke8pTW1rSU9CWEtrYzQ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default vertical alignment of a `tabular` (unless specified otherwise) is at the centre, while those of images are its baseline. These vertical alignment locations can be seen as anchor points and they align with one another if placed on the same horizontal line. Here's a quick demonstration:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

x
\includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{example-image}
x
\begin{tabular}{c} \hline a \\ b \\ c \\ \hline \end{tabular}
x
\begin{tabular}[t]{c} \hline a \\ b \\ c \\ \hline \end{tabular}
x
\begin{tabular}[b]{c} \hline a \\ b \\ c \\ \hline \end{tabular}
x
\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{tabular}[b]{c} \hline a \\ b \\ c \\ \hline \end{tabular}}
x
\adjustbox{valign=T}{\begin{tabular}[b]{c} \hline a \\ b \\ c \\ \hline \end{tabular}}
x
\adjustbox{valign=b}{\begin{tabular}[b]{c} \hline a \\ b \\ c \\ \hline \end{tabular}}
x
\adjustbox{valign=B}{\begin{tabular}[b]{c} \hline a \\ b \\ c \\ \hline \end{tabular}}
x

\bigskip\bigskip

x
\includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip,valign=c]{example-image}
x
\begin{tabular}{c} a \\ b \\ c \end{tabular}
x

\end{document}
```

With the above in mind, you can either align the image to its vertical centre (rather than the baseline), or align the `tabular` to its `B`aseline (rather than its vertical centre) to align the two images.

However, you're still left with two objects of differing heights, and this might be off-putting. I've taken your code and added some pizzaz to it, including the use of `valign` modifications for the image and `tabular`, as well as using [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs). Note the use of a consistent `height` for each of the images in the legend (subfigure (b)); this provides consistency across the rows of the table without having to guess an appropriate `scale`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[format=acmsmall, review=false, screen=true]{acmart}

\usepackage{subfig,booktabs,makecell}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[]
    {\includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth]{OSM_copy.png}}\quad
  \subfloat[]
    {\adjustbox{width=0.5\columnwidth,valign=B,raise=2\baselineskip}{%
      \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
      \begin{tabular}{ *{4}{c} }
        \toprule
        \bfseries \makecell[b]{Location \\ type} & \bfseries Index & 
          \bfseries \makecell[b]{Location \\ type} & \bfseries Index \\
        \midrule
        Bar          & \includegraphics[height=12pt,valign=c]{index_bar.png}       & 
          Taxi stand       & \includegraphics[height=12pt,valign=c]{index_taxi.png}     \\
        Food court   & \includegraphics[height=12pt,valign=c]{index_foodcourt.png} & 
          Hospital         & \includegraphics[height=12pt,valign=c]{index_hospital.png} \\
        Library      & \includegraphics[height=12pt,valign=c]{index_library.png}   & 
          Pharmacy         & \includegraphics[height=12pt,valign=c]{index_pharmacy.png} \\
        Fuel station & \includegraphics[height=12pt,valign=c]{index_fuel.png}      & 
          Movie theater    & \includegraphics[height=12pt,valign=c]{index_movie.png}    \\
        Parking      & \includegraphics[height=12pt,valign=c]{index_parking.png}   & 
          Public telephone & \includegraphics[height=12pt,valign=c]{index_phone.png}    \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}}
    }
  \caption{%
    (a) An area in Taipei showing different location types.
    (b) Some of the location types defined in OSM.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I think the operative line in your solution is `\adjustbox{width=0.5\columnwidth,valign=B,raise=2\baselineskip}`. By adjusting the parameters in only this line, one can achieve the desired result. Nonetheless, your detailed response helped me learn something new.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that uses a `tabularx` environment instead of `tabular`. It also uses some of the macros of the `booktabs` package to give the tabular material a more open space. Finally, it employs the `subcaption` package. (I used the 'demo' option since I don't have access to the various image files; omit the 'demo' option in your real code.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[format=acmsmall, review=false, screen=true, 
               demo]{acmart} % remove 'demo' option in real document

\usepackage{multicol} % Q: Do you really need this package? 
\usepackage{balance}   
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption} % Load 'subcaption' instead of 'subfig'
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.42\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{OSM_copy.png}
\caption{} \label{OSM}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill% Maximize the distance between the two subfigure environments
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.55\textwidth}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Cm{10mm}Cm{10mm}@{}}
Location Type & Index & Location Type & Index  \\ 
\midrule
Bar              & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\linewidth]{index_bar.png} & 
Taxi stand       & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\linewidth]{index_taxi.png}\\ 
\addlinespace
Food court       & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\linewidth]{index_foodcourt.png} & 
Hospital         & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\linewidth]{index_hospital.png} \\ 
\addlinespace
Library          & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\linewidth]{index_library.png} & 
Pharmacy         & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\linewidth]{index_pharmacy.png} \\ 
\addlinespace
Fuel station     & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\linewidth]{index_fuel.png} & 
Movie theater    & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\linewidth]{index_movie.png} \\ 
\addlinespace
Parking          & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\linewidth]{index_parking.png} & 
Public telephone & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\linewidth]{index_phone.png} \\
\end{tabularx}
\caption{} \label{table2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption[]{(a) An area in Taipei showing different location types. 
           (b) Some of the location types defined in OSM. }
\label{fig:location}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```